# C# VSTO Excel NamedRange Change event: Iterate the range

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am creating a VSTO solution for an Excel sheet that has got a namedRange that contains 16 rows and 3 colums (so 48 Cells in total). When one of these cells is altered, I need to iterate all of the 48 cells to make some calculations. 
I tried to add a Change event to the namedRange but the problem is that this only allows me to acess the currently altered cell. Is there a possibility to iterate all cells of a namedRange when one of them gets altered?

Thanks, David

Comment: Yes, but you haven't shown code, so we are guessing what your setup is. If you have the cell as a Target Object, then you can check if the cell is in the Named Range and iterate through. Please show some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with the SheetChange event, some conditional logic and an enumerator from the named range.

I have included comments for clarity. Hope this helps.

Updated:
Included a check to ensure the CHANGED cell is within the NAMED RANGE. This way it avoids unnecessary processing if the cell on the sheet is changed but not within the NAMED RANGE (at the cost of some conditional logic).

```
    //must be declared in scope
    Range myNamedRange;

    private void SetupEventHandlerForRange(Workbook wb, String namedRange)
    {
        //get the Range object of the namedRange
        myNamedRange = wb.Worksheets.GetRangeByName(namedRange);
        //subscribe to the SheetChange event
        this.SheetChange += new
            Excel.WorkbookEvents_SheetChangeEventHandler(
            CheckNamedRangeOnCellChange);
    }

    void CheckNamedRangeOnCellChange(object Sh, Excel.Range Target)
    {
        //get the Worksheet object
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Sh;
        //check if worksheet is the desired sheet name (optional)
        if(sheet.Name == "The Name Of The Sheet You Want To Check")
        {
            //will stay false until it finds a cell in range
            bool cellInRange = false;
            //get the range enumerator for the ALTERED range
            IEnumerator altRangeEnum = Target.GetEnumerator();

            while (altRangeEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                //get the cell object and check if it is in the namedRange
                Cell cell = (Cell)altRangeEnum.Current;
                cellInRange = IsCellIsInRange(cell, myNamedRange);
                //if the cell is in the namedRange break
                //we want to continue if any of the cells altered are in
                //the namedRange
                if(cellInRange) break;
            }

            //changed cell is not in namedRange, return
            if(!cellInRange) return;

            //get the range enumerator
            IEnumerator rangeEnum = myNamedRange.GetEnumerator();

            while (rangeEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                Cell cell = (Cell)rangeEnum.Current;
                //do something with cell
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsCellInRange(Cell cell, Range range)
    {
        if (cell.Row < range.Row ||
            cell.Row > range.Column ||
            cell.Column < range.Row + range.Rows.Count - 1 ||
            cell.Column > range.Column + range.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
              //cell is outside the range we want to check
              return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```